# Requestion about one of the wrong outputs of ValidatePIN

Tags: if-statement, assembly, x86, irvine32

The program is working perfect except the invalid output of `samplepin_3` which should be `5` but it displays `4`. What am I missing here?

```
 ; 32-bit assembly language template

; INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

INCLUDELIB C:\Irvine\Kernel32.lib
INCLUDELIB C:\Irvine\Irvine32.lib
INCLUDE C:\Irvine\Irvine32.inc

pbyte typedef ptr byte                          ; pointer to bytes

.data
VALID_PIN = 0
PIN_SIZE = 5
minVals byte 5,2,4,1,3                  ; globally visible
maxVals byte 9,5,8,4,6                  ; globally visible
samplePin_1 byte 6,3,4,4,3              ; valid PIN
samplePin_2 byte 5,2,3,2,4              ; digit 3 is invalid
samplePin_3 byte 5,2,4,5,3              ; digit 5 is invalid
samplePin_4 byte 1,3,4,4,3              ; digit 1 is invalid

ptr1 pbyte samplePin_1                          ; points to array samplePin_1
ptr2 pbyte samplePin_2                          ; points to array samplePin_2
ptr3 pbyte samplePin_3                          ; points to array samplePin_3
ptr4 pbyte samplePin_4                          ; points to array samplePin_4
ptr5 pbyte minVals                              ; points to array minVals
ptr6 pbyte maxVals                              ; points to array maxVals

ValidPINMsg byte "The PIN is valid     ", 0    ;
InvalidPINMsg byte "The PIN is invalid.  The invalid digit is     ", 0 ;

.code
main proc

mov eax,VALID_PIN                  ; 

mov edi,ptr5
mov ebp,ptr6

mov esi,ptr1
call ValidatePIN                   ; determine whether or not the PIN is valid
.IF eax == 0
 mov edx,OFFSET ValidPINMsg
 call WriteString
 call WaitMsg
 call Crlf
.ELSE
 mov edx,OFFSET InvalidPINMsg
 call WriteString
 call WriteDec
 call WaitMsg
 call Crlf
.ENDIF

mov esi,ptr2
mov edi,ptr5
mov ebp,ptr6
call ValidatePIN                   ; determine whether or not the PIN is valid                       
.IF eax == 0
 mov edx,OFFSET ValidPINMsg
 call WriteString
 call WaitMsg
 call Crlf
.ELSE
 mov edx,OFFSET InvalidPINMsg
 call WriteString
 call WriteDec
 call WaitMsg
 call Crlf
.ENDIF

mov esi,ptr3
mov edi,ptr5
mov ebp,ptr6
call ValidatePIN                   ; determine whether or not the PIN is valid                       
.IF eax == 0
 mov edx,OFFSET ValidPINMsg
 call WaitMsg
 call Crlf
.ELSE
 mov edx,OFFSET InvalidPINMsg
 call WriteString
 call WriteDec
 call WaitMsg
 call Crlf
.ENDIF

mov esi,ptr4
mov edi,ptr5
mov ebp,ptr6
call ValidatePIN                   ; determine whether or not the pin is valid                       
.IF eax == 0
 mov edx,OFFSET ValidPINMsg
 call WriteString
 call WaitMsg
 call Crlf
.ELSE
 mov edx,OFFSET InvalidPINMsg
 call WriteString
 call WriteDec
 call WaitMsg
 call Crlf
.ENDIF

main endp

ValidatePIN PROC
 mov ecx,PIN_SIZE

 .REPEAT

mov al, byte ptr [esi]
.IF (al < [edi]) || (al > [ebp])
    neg ecx
    add ecx, 6
    jmp L1
.ELSE
 add esi,1
 add edi,1
 add ebp,1
.ENDIF

dec ecx    

.UNTIL ecx == 0

L1: 
 mov eax,ecx
 ret

ret
ValidatePIN ENDP
END main
```

Comment: That's because computers **can** count. Digit #4 is invalid, which does happen to be a `5`, but you print the 1-based index, so `4` is totally correct.

Comment: Yes but I don't know how to make the invalid output of `samplePin_3` to become `5`.

Comment: Let me say again, `4` is the correct answer ... the only way to make it `5` is to change the data in `samplePin_3` for example to `samplePin_3 byte 5,2,4,3,5`

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand. If I compare `samplePin_3` values between `minVals` and `maxVals`, only `5` is invalid. Isn't it should be `5` not `4`?

Comment: Your code prints the **index** (position) of the wrong  value not the value itself (contrary to the message). `5` is the wrong value, but it's in position `4`, so `4` is printed. You were just lucky that for `samplePin_2` and `samplePin_4` the index and value match (digit `3` is the third, and digit `1` is the first one).